# Configuration files BROKER_DATABASE_HOST Docker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm trying to access the ContextBroker configuration file in the path `/etc/sysconfig/contextBroker` and it's empty. What is the problem?

https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/running/index.html

I'm using Docker.

Also I am testing the installation by yum centos and tells me that the repository is wrong.

Is it copied from the web?

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/admin/yum.md

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/sysconfig/contextBroker` is used in RPM-base deployment. Docker is based in compiling Context Broker directly from sources, as you can see in [the docker file](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile).

So, in this case, you have to use [CLI based configuration](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/cli/index.html). Note the docker is built with some of them:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/contextBroker","-fg", "-multiservice", "-ngsiv1Autocast" ]
```

But you can add aditional ones. For example, in the [reference docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/docker/docker-compose.yml) we set `-dbhost`, and more ones could be added in the same way.

```
command: -dbhost mongo
```

I guess that using `docker run` you could also add commands in the same way `command` works in docker-compose.yml, although I don't know the details. Maybe some docker expert could add more info :)